# how to use . point into javascript variable name

Tags: javascript

I have and API that return an Array of object like the following:

```
{
  "form_submit.form_submit_id": 7987,
  "form_submit.exported": false,
  "form_submit.updatedAt": "2016-01-18T16:13:16.813Z",
  "form_submit.user.user_id": 14,
  "form_submit.user.name": "Hugo Bismarck",
},
```

If I use the . on my javascript for example to get the first element

```
var test = array[0].form_submit.form_submit_id;
```

get the following error

```
array[0].form_submit.form_submit_id is undefined
```

the problem is that the name of the attributes have points, so how can acces to this attributes?

Comment: Why don't you just switch to underscores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in this case the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

> property_name is a string. The string does not have to be a valid identifier; it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

```
var test = array[0]['form_submit.form_submit_id'];
```